# Is there any way I can test the performance of XF and the ability of the phone to create new elements?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to understand how my XF application performs with different models of phones. Specifically the time it take to draw new pages or change the structure of existing pages.

Does anyone know of any simple way to test the ability of the phone to draw out for example something like a text label 500 times so that I could then use C# stopwatch to measure the time it took to do that event?

Comment: https://testcloud.xamarin.com/

Comment: Thanks Jason but I have a mode on the phone that a dev can switch to and I am just looking for some way to set the C# Stopwatch, do some operation a lot of times, Stop the stopwatch and put to the screen a value.  The display on the screen and stopwatch is no problem but not sure how I could add an element multiple times and then remove it in a way that it could be timed.

Comment: myStackLayout.Add(new Label() { Text = "test text" } );

Comment: Yes that looks good.  But if I put that in a loop and add many times then how can I also remove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add an element dynamically

```
myStackLayout.Add(new Label { Text = "test test" });
```

you can remove all the children

```
myStackLayout.Children.Clear();
```

or a single child, by reference or by index

```
myStackLayout.Children.Remove(element);
myStackLayout.Children.RemoveAt(index);
```